# Incompatible operand types

Tags: java

I have created a class and its child. Now, I need to check if the child is the instance of parent but I get Incompatible operand types.

```
class Vehicle {

}

class Car extends Vehicle {

}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicle v = new Vehicle();
        Car c = new Car();

        if (c instanceof v) {
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `c instanceof Vehicle`

Comment: A Car will always be an instance of Vehicle, since Car extends Vehicle. This test is thus useless: it will always be true.

Answer (score 5):

The `instanceof` keyword needs to be used as

```
ReferenceTypeExpression instanceof ReferenceType
```

You are using it as

```
ReferenceTypeExpression instanceof ReferenceTypeExpression
```

You should instead have

```
if (c instanceof Vehicle) {
```

The above explains the correct use of the `instanceof` operator, but take note of [JB Nizet's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513962/incompatible-operand-types/21513976#comment32481183_21513962).

Comment: Off topic Ques - How did you linked `JB Nizet's` comment ? Mean to ask how did u found that internal link ?

Comment: @sansix It's in the time since post link, eg. `10 mins ago`, in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`isAssignableFrom()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) method in `Class` class.

```
if (c.getClass().isAssignableFrom(v.getClass())) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instanceof needs to compare reference variable a with class b.